# spring oauth2 token Handling error

Tags: spring, security, oauth

Currently I use spring mvc oauth2 to secure my web application.

I tried to do  curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/project/oauth/token?client_id=the_client&grant_type=password&username=user&password=password&response_type=token"

I got reply.
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."}

Then I checked the code of TokenEndpoint.java, It show the Principal is null.

The exception is  Handling error: InsufficientAuthenticationException, There is no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter.

Here is the spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns:oauth2="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd">

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />
<bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.DefaultUserApprovalHandler" />

<!--client -->
<bean id="clientDetailsService" class="oauth2.CustomJdbcClientDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="clientDetailsUserDetailsService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>
<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<oauth2:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth2:authorization-code />
    <oauth2:implicit />
    <oauth2:refresh-token />
    <oauth2:client-credentials />
    <oauth2:password />
</oauth2:authorization-server>
<security:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>
<!--client -->

<!--user -->
<bean id="userService" class="services.UserServicesImpl" />
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userService">
        <!--<security:password-encoder hash="md5"/> -->
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
<!--user -->

<oauth2:resource-server id="mobileResourceServer"
    resource-id="mobile-resource" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="false">
    <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**"
        access="ROLE_DRIVER" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="mobileResourceServer"
        before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>
```

I don't know why it is wrong, Please help me thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide a query parameter named "client_secret" for the client authentication.